# How does a detail page button which is invoking a flow works?

Tags: apex, custom-button, invocable-method, flow-builder

I have a flow where I am passing a Custom Object's recordId to the flow by invoking it from a detail page button like this `/flow/Activate_Record/myRecordId?={!Inactive_Farms__c.Id}` 
This flow is invoking a Apex class with parameter `List<Inactive_Farms__c> iFarms`.
Now, can someone help me understand if the button is clicked by multiple users at the same time, is it considered as a single transaction? Is the why InvocableMethod allows only List type? 
I am not able to determine if I have to query as `Inactive_Farms__c if = [Select Id, Farm_Id From Inactive_Farm__c Where Id = :iFarms` assuming only one record per click

Or

Query `List<Inactive_Farms__c> if = [Select Id, Farm_Id From Inactive_Farm__c Where Id IN :iFarms]` because multiple records will be passed?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InvocableMethods can be called from autolaunched flows (process builder), which could be operating on multiple records at once.  For this reason, their inputs can only be List types.  Different users always have separate transactions.

If your method accepts `List<Inactive_Farms__c> iFarms`, then the flow should retrieve the records, and the method won't need to query.  The method could also accept `List<Id> iFarms`, which relieves the flow of record retrieval, and requires a query. Use the `List<Inactive_Farms__c> if = [Select Id, Farm_Id From Inactive_Farm__c Where Id IN :iFarms]` query if you are taking the List-of-IDs approach.

Either way, loop through the list in the method.  In your page button scenario, this list will only contain one record, but you need to account for the possibility that other records will be included if invoked from somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you @MatthewGTS. That is exactly what i wanted to hear. I thought i might over complicating the logic making it accountable for multiple records.